# sshfs with multiple clients

Tags: linux, debian, sshfs

I have a server running under Debian 8. It has an SSH and an SFTP server running properly and I use them without any problem.

I installed win-sshfs on my computer so I can access to my SFTP transparently from the Windows Explorer which works great. I can do anything as if I was on a local drive. I installed win-sshfs on another computer and it does work as well.

Now, I'd like those two computers to be able to access to the SFTP using sshfs at the same time (only read access on some files).

Here's the issue, if a client has already mounted the drive via SSHFS, if I try to mount it on the other computer, I get this error message "Channel was closed" and it's impossible to mount it. As soon as I will unmount it from the first computer, I'll be able to mount it on the other one without any trouble.

Any idea on how to mount it on two computers (or more) at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your `/etc/fstab` file config. It may be you need to use `allow_other`
See this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS) for more details.

Alternatively, you can try using CIFS since your connecting clients are windows hosts.
There is also NFS as another option.

Hope this helps.